# Checking whether this function has essential discontinuity or removable discontinuity

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

let $$f(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{3x^4+2y^2}$$

So I can easily see that I get a different limit while moving on the parabola $y=x^2$ and $y=x$

This would only mean that the limit doesn't exist which makes it an essential discontinuity.

But check this out :

Define $p=(x,y)$ and we can observe that $|x|≤|p|$ and $|y|≤|p|$

Therefore we can conclude that $$0≤|f(x,y)|≤\frac{|p|}{3|p|^2+2}$$

And here let $|p|->0$ and by, sandwich theorem $|f(x,y)|->0$ , thus the limit exists.

Isn't this a contradiction? Limit shouldn't exist, What is the wrong with the way I solve then?

Comment: Are you saying $\frac{1}{|3x^4 + 2y^2|} \leq \frac{1}{3|x|^4 + 3|y|^2} \leq \frac{1}{3|p|^4 + 3|p|^2}$?  That wouldn't be right.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Okay I see my small mistake. What if i were to prove a two variable function has limit at a certain point. I can't look for all the paths that lead to it, I need a proof not a counterexample, what kind of steps should I have taken then?

Comment: Note: $|x|,|y|\le |p|$ is not the same as $ $|x|,|y|= |p|.$

Comment: That would be the proper sequence of steps.  But, in this case, you won't be able to do that because your first argument is valid.  That is, there is no limit.